# How to use meta tag in HTML

Tags: html, meta

I want to create a link which will delay for 5 seconds before directing to the data. I am told the meta tag ca be used for this.

Please have a look at my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> ABC.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width=768>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC.com Logo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="http://www.google.com"> LOGIN </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"> copyright abc.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <title> ABC.com</title>
</head>
<body> 
 <table border = "1" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" width = 768>
 <tr> 
  <td>ABC.com Logo </td>
 </tr>
 <tr >  
  <td align = "center"> 
   <a href="http://www.google.com"> LOGIN </a>  
  </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr> 
  <td align = "right"> copyright abc.com </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://example.com/somepage.html">
```

The "5" is your 5 second delay, and the URL is whatever page you want to redirect to.

And by the way, as a beginning developer, [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/#q=meta%20refresh).

Comment: ok thank you.  And what should i do if i want to give a notification when it is refreshing? Example like "please wait while we log you in"

Comment: Just add that message to the body somewhere, like `<h1>Logging in, please wait...</h1>`